# Pointing to a double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a function which takes a double pointer as a parameter. I noticed that expressions like this `char *tmp = arr[i];` work, where `arr` is a `char **arr` pointer. The whole function looks like this :

```
void string_sort(char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if(cmp_func(arr[i], arr[j]) > 0)
            {
                char *tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is - why is `arr[i]` considered an address and not a dereferenced pointer? (I understand that a double pointer "points" to another pointer's address, but I don't understand why this syntax is valid). Can you give an example of an equivalent expression without an array-like syntax?

Comment: Since `arr` is `char **`, `arr[i]` is a `char *`. It *is* a dereferenced pointer, but since it was pointing to other pointers, it's also an address (of some `char`).

Comment: OK, so ```*(arr + i) = *(&i) = i```, but ```**(arr + i) = *(*(arr + i)) = *(i)```.

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what you're trying to say here. No, there is no sense in which `*(arr + i)` = `*(&i)`. `*(arr + i)` is another way to write `arr[i]`, that is, the `i`th element of array `arr`, or the contents of the block of memory `i` elements beyond the starting address of `arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Hello";

    printf( "%p -> %s\n", ( void * )s, s );

    char **t = &s;

    printf( "%p -> %p ->  %s\n", ( void * )t, ( void * )*t, *t );
    printf( "%p -> %p ->  %s\n", ( void * )t, ( void * )t[0], *t );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0x55a06f99c004 -> Hello
0x7ffc051a83d8 -> 0x55a06f99c004 ->  Hello
0x7ffc051a83d8 -> 0x55a06f99c004 ->  Hello
```

That is the pointer `s` points to the first character of the string literal `"Hello"`.

The pointer `t` points to the pointer `s` that in turn points to the first character of the string literal `"Hello"`.

For example if you have a declaration like this

```
char *s = "Hello";
```

then the both expression `s[0]` and `*s` have the type `char` and yield the first character of the string literal that is `'H'`.

Another example. If you have an array of integers

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

then the number of its elements can be calculated either like

```
sizeof( a ) / sizeof( a[0] )
```

or like

```
sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )
```

[Though you may even write like

```
sizeof( a ) / sizeof( a[1000] )
```

because the used expression is not evaluated. It is important only the size of an object of the type int. SO you could also write

```
sizeof( a ) / sizeof( int )
```

-end note]

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is valid because `arr[i]` is literally *the exact same* as `*(arr + i)`. This is also an example without using array subscript syntax, BTW.

> ...why is `arr[i]` considered an address and not a dereferenced pointer?

Yes, `arr[i]` *is* a dereferenced pointer, as discussed above. It's also an address because when you dereference a pointer to a pointer (`char **arr`), you get a pointer - an address.